# How to remove the gap in bootstrap div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See my fiddle location. http://fiddle.jshell.net/gpyrq2e4/1/

**Used Bootstrap**

I want to remove the space between the grey and black area. In responsive view, I want the gap to increase.

**MY Html Is:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">small text</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">large texttt tttttttttttttttt</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">A large gap displayed.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like this......

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ddd;">
       .col-xs-12 .col-md-8.col-xs-12 .col-md-8.
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:#000; color:#fff;">
                .col-xs-6 .col-md-4
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ddd;">
          .col-xs-6 .col-md-4.col-xs-6 .col-md-4.col-xs-6 .col-md-4.col-xs-6 .col-md-4
    </div> 
</div>
```

Live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/55rLn2en/)

> You must have to put `row` class into `container` class.

Answer (score 0):

since they are all inside the same div give a class to the div (.example) and try this:

```
.example {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This works in a way, but I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want. If it's not I'll try another way.

Comment: NOt working. If i tried this css content not wraping.